# Cannot use SqlCeDataReader.HasRow

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, datareader

**[EDIT]**
I changed my code according to the your answers. But now I get another error:

**IndexOutOfRangeException was Handled.**

I have an empty table to begin with. Weird..

Below is my code. Any idea?

```
using (SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        dg2.Items.Add(new DataItem2() { FooName = (string)rdr["FooName"],});
    }
    rdr.Close();
}
```

**[EDIT - 2nd]**
I edited my code and use rdr[0] instead of rdr["String"], I get a different error

**"Index was outside the bounds of the array."**

omg, this is driving my nuts. I have absolutely empty rows to start with and I have no idea how these strange errors pop up

```
using (SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        dg2.Items.Add(new DataItem2() { FooName = (string)rdr[0],});
    }
    rdr.Close();
}
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/86400fbd-b842-4012-9480-be2f55a789b4/

Comment: if you are using `using` then Dispose() is called which calls `Close()` so you can skip calling `Close()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message says, HasRows is not supported. You should be fine skipping that check. Also using `using` is recommended in these situations.

```
using(SqlCeDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        dg2.Items.Add(new DataItem2() { FooName = (string)rdr["FooName"] });
    }
}
```

Comment: @KMC must be from `rdr["FooName"]`; I'm not sure about your select query but try doing `rdr[0]` and see if that resolves it.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `HasRows` if statement.  You can loop through readers by doing `while (rdr.Read())`.  It will return false (skip while) if no records are returned.  (At least with SqlDataReaders)

Comment: see my edited question according to what you suggest, I get a different error

Comment: That sounds like the column name you're looking for in the reader isn't found.  Try doing `rdr[0]` instead of `rdr["FooName"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you use SqlCeDataReader to return an aggregate value such as Max() it doesn't seem to allow you to check for a null. [This occurs if there are no rows]
IsDbNull(0) raised an error, so my solution was just to try to read the value and Catch the System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException that will be raised.